# How to change car body color with opencv on python or javascript

Tags: opencv

How to change the car color to ff6700 and keep the shadow effect on the hood

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIvJm.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.  Basically, treat the gray image as the value channel of HSV. Then create a saturation and a hue channel and combine. Then convert back to BGR.

This would work better if you had a mask for the windows and for the red rear lights so that they would not get colorized.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image with alpha
img = cv2.imread("gray_car.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract bgr channels
bgr = img[:,:,0:3]

# extract alpha channel
alpha = img[:,:,3]

# convert bgr to gray as value channel
V = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create saturation channel
S = np.full_like(V, (128))

# create blue hue channel
# blue is hue=240, but in OpenCV divide by 2
H = np.full_like(V, (120))

# merge HSV
hsv = cv2.merge([H,S,V])

# convert hsv to bgr
bgr_colorized = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# put alpha channel back
result = bgr_colorized.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = alpha

# save result
cv2.imwrite('gray_car_colorized.png', result)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]